# How to create a reusable $http data service in AngularJS the recommended way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, factory

I've expanded on Misko Heverey's excellent best-practices [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850025/recommended-way-of-getting-data-from-the-server) about a recommended way of accessing $http resources from a backend.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to DRY it up so that I can make it reusable.  It seems that few people writing reusable service components are using Misko's method of returning `new Things()` that encapsulate their own server operations (like Active Record design pattern).  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389291/angularjs-with-oop-inheritance-in-action) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102121/is-it-possible-and-in-good-form-to-reuse-the-same-data-factory-in-angular).

The vision is a single base service that defines the CRUD functions and then child services which define a resource url and use the methods from the base service.  Here's the code I'd like to break apart:

```
app.factory('Thing', function($http,$q) {

    // constructor
    var Thing = function(data) {
        angular.extend(this, data);
    };

    var urlBase = 'https://api.resourceendpoint.com/1/class/things';

    // static methods to retrieve items by id or entire list
    Thing.read = function(id) {
        return $http.get(urlBase + '/' + id).then(
            function(response) {
                // success
                return new Thing(response.data);
            },
            function(response) {
                // failure
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        );
    };
    Thing.list = function() {
        return $http.get(urlBase).then(
            function(response) {
                // success
                var items = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < response.data.results.length; i++) {
                    items.push(new Thing(response.data.results[i]));
                }
                return items;
            },
            function (response) {
                // failure
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        );
    };

    // instance CRUD methods for Thing
    Thing.prototype.insert = function() {
        var item = this;
        return $http.post(urlBase, item).then(
            function(response) {
                // success
                item.objectId = response.data.objectId;
                return item;
            },
            function(response) {
                // failure
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        );
    };
    Thing.prototype.update = function() {
        var item = this;
        return $http.put(urlBase + '/' + item.objectId, item).then(
            function(response) {
                // success
                return item;
            },
            function(response) {
                // failure
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        );
    };
    Thing.prototype.remove = function() {
        var item = this;
        return $http.delete(urlBase + '/' + item.objectId).then(
            function(response) {
                // success
            },
            function(response) {
                // failure
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        );
    };

    return Thing;
});
```

Comment: This reminded me of the [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: Why aren't you using $resource it does exactly that

Comment: That's an excellent question. I'm learning angular and haven't studied $resource yet. Maybe I should just read the source. I was hoping to learn something about prototypical inheritance by doing it myself.